# How to add another field to an existing Lucene index?

Tags: lucene, text-mining, information-retrieval

I have a lucene index that contains documents with the following fields: num(IntField), title(TextField,stored), contents(TextField,not stored)
I want to add a field to this index. I tried this (after finding the documentId, both the reader and the writer are open and q is a query that i used to find documentId):

```
Document doc = indexreader.document(documentId);
doc.add(new TextField("terms",terms,Store.YES));  

writer.deleteDocuments(q);
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

However, when I try to query the index for the newly edited document , i can't seem to find it.

edit:it worked perfectly before I added the field, and it still works for other documents that I haven't edited.

Comment: How are you searching for it again? Are you reopening the searcher?

Comment: it's a FS directory , i'm using a totally different code to read it. so yes , i basically close everything.

Comment: Can you show how you're building your queries and maybe some example queries?

Comment: nothing special, i'm reading the query from 'system.in" then parsing it. it worked perfectly before I added the field, and it still works for other documents that i haven't edited

Comment: I suggest inspecting your index using [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases) to troubleshoot.

Comment: Are all of the fields stored?  Or are you attempting to query on a field that is indexed, but not stored?

Comment: as you can see in the question, the "contents" field is not stored. but what i'm querying on is the "num"

Comment: Keep in mind, After you update the index you have to close index writer and open new index ready, So it sees the changes. OR, you have to use NRT reader( writer.reopen() ) to get in memory documents flushed immediately and get new reader on top of them. See it here: http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html